# Java does not recognize ListView variable

Tags: java, android, listview

I trying to create a ListView in AndroidStudio with value "nome". I created a list and a adapter for this, but my application not recognize variable "services".

**This is my activity code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String service;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item1);


        ArrayAdapter<Services> servicesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Services>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, services); <-- in this line
        listView.setAdapter(servicesAdapter);

    }


    private List<Services> gerarServices(){
        List<Services> services  = new ArrayList<Services>();
        services.add(criarServices("Home"));
        services.add(criarServices("Delivery"));

        return services;
    }

    private Services criarServices(String nome){
        Services service = new Services(nome);
        return service;
    }
}
```

Any suggestion? Thank's in advance!

Comment: There is no variable called `services` that is in-scope in `onCreate`

Comment: I suggest you learn about scope of local variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `services` variable is not in the scope of your `onCreate` method. As mentioned by @Code-Apprentice, you might want to find out more about scope of local variables.

So, what you might want to do is to invoke the `gerarServices()` method in the `onCreate` method and assign it to a local variable which will then be passed to the `ArrayAdapter`. Like so:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item1);

    List<Services> services = gerarServices();


    ArrayAdapter<Services> servicesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Services>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, services);
    listView.setAdapter(servicesAdapter);

}
```

**or**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item1);


    ArrayAdapter<Services> servicesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Services>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, gerarServices());
    listView.setAdapter(servicesAdapter);

}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The information in this answer is very good. Thank you for contributing to Stack Overflow. I just have one nitpick. The OP seems to not understand about variable scope. Starting the answer with "don't you think..." can seem a little condescending. Please edit your question to improve the tone and helpfulness of your answer. You might also consider giving a brief explanation of the scope of a variable.

Comment: thanks for the gentle reprimand @[Code-Apprentice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1440565/code-apprentice), Just starting to become an 'active' member of the community. Definitely still got a lot to learn...

Comment: Just helping to improve the content here. Good to see new people join and contribute.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, I dont see any mehod for declaring and initializing `services`.
But `gerarServices()` return a list of `Services`. So I guess you have to do above action(s) before using any variables or instances of class, etc.
Like so,

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item1);

// Add this line of code
List<Services> services = gerarServices();

ArrayAdapter<Services> servicesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Services>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, services);
```

Hope this help.